# Show stream of IP camera in modern browsers

Tags: browser, streaming, video-streaming, ip-camera, rtsp

My camera has RTSP and i know that RTSP cannot be played in modern browsers. What is the best way to show live stream from IP camera in my web application. I need open source solution and if it possible to be real time

Comment: Have you looked at [VLC](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.en.html)?

Comment: Yes, but i need live stream to be embeded in the browser.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61672575/rtsp-to-webrtc-live-video-streaming on Stack Overflow answer your question?

Comment: @user1686 yes, thank you so much! I will try to embed solution in my web application. Hopefully... It is Laravel web app...